# How can I change the item body in beamer LaTeX

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize, overlays

In the following code, I want to show item 5 in place of item 1. How I can fix that, or is it possible to change the name of an item? For example, in this case, the item `point1` will be `point5` in slide 5. For example, I can change the color of the item `point1` in slide 5 (see the commented line).

```
\documentclass[compress,red]{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}%les accents pour mac
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{movie 15}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all,knot]{xy}
\xyoption{arc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
%\usepackage{multimedia}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\begin{document}
\section{section1 }
\frame[shrink]{\frametitle{Titre de la fenetre}
\begin{itemize}
%\item<1-> \color<5>[rgb]{0,0.6,0} point1
\item<1-4> point1
\item<2-4> point2
\item<3-4> point3
\item<4> point4
\item<5> point5
\end{itemize}

}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My logic would go like this: \item<1-4,5>\visible<1-4>{point1}\visible<5>{point5}. But this will generate a blank space before point5.

Comment: Please make your example [minimal](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: @SvendTveskæg, I think that my example is very small. Please, ignore the negative comment. Let us work.

Comment: @Jesse, thanks jessy. But it is not very well. Surely, there is a solution

Comment: It is good practice to make ones code as simpel as possible when asking for help.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg, In fact, my question is small.But may be the issue is I put a lot of package, but the body is small.

Comment: Indeed it is the packages I'm referring to. (When you get time to read the page I've linked to ("minimal" is hyperlinked), please do it.)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

I resolve the problem using `\alt`;

```
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-4,5>\alt<5>{point5}{point1}  
\item<2-4> point2
\item<3-4> point3
\item<4> point4
\end{itemize}
```